# Rigidity for convex surfaces in elliptic/hyperbolic space

Tags: surfaces, curvature, spheres, convex-geometry, metric-geometry

From Alexandrov's work we know that any metric on the sphere with lower curvature bound $\kappa$ (in the sense of Alexandrov) can be realized as a closed convex surface (i.e. boundary of a convex domain) in the 3-space form of constant curvature $\kappa$.

For $\kappa=0$, the surface is unique up to isometry of the sorrounding space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is the same true for the elliptic and hyperbolic case? In other words, are isometric closed convex surface in these space congruent as well?

Comment: The answer is yes, as I just [posted on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393787/rigidity-for-convex-surfaces-in-elliptic-hyperbolic-space/449321#449321).